# Background Gradient - Fill Page without scroll bars or repeating

Tags: css, gradient

I have a background gradient and it looks great but I have one problem, on short pages the background is too long and causes unnecessary scroll bars and on long pages the background will start to repeat instead of stretching to fill the entire page.

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
html, body{
font-size:1em;
font-family: "ff-dagny-web-pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height:1.438em;
color:#222;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: justify;
background: rgb(0,0,0); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(25%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(209,209,209,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#d1d1d1',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

When I add `height: 100%;` it causes scroll bars on short pages. I attempted to remove them by using `overflow: hidden;` but that caused any content on long pages to not show! Also if I do not use `height: 100%;` then the gradient only fills about half the page and repeats.

I am a bit perplexed as to what to do or try to solve this issue.

Note: While I would prefer a CSS solution, if there is a javascript solution (using jQuery) that works I would be willing to attempt that to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What caused this issue was my attempt to implement a "Sticky Footer". I removed all height requirements (IE: `min-height` and `height`) and the browser adjust accordingly without issue.

As a side-note, I used the following code to solve my sticky footer issue:

```
$(function() {
    var height = $(window).height() - ($("header").outerHeight() + $("footer").outerHeight() );
    $("#page-content").css("min-height",height+"px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

..........................

Hi now used to `min-height:100%`

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/NhB9kCCY)***

Comment: But the height causes a scroll bar on short pages which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: @Lynda Than you can used to a particular div as like this http://tinkerbin.com/u8Z8QOH0

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100%;` to your CSS rule and it will be fixed.

Comment: But the height causes a scroll bar on short pages which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: Your `<body>` will never be shorter than browser's inner height, could you show me an example of code that this causes scroll bar on it?