# Is it possible to get the html element to contain everything

Tags: css

I'm working on a webpage where i would like to have a gradient going from the top of the page to the bottom, but the html does not physical hold all the elements.

At this point i have tried everything i can think of from checking if there was a floating element that wasn't accounted for to setting overflow-y on both and separately html and body to auto, hidden and scoll just to mention few.

```
<body><div id='main'>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="events"></div>
</div></body>


*{
    font-size: 62,5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EDE8B9 20%, #B7C35D);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #EDE8B9 20%, #B7C35D);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #EDE8B9 20%, #B7C35D);
}

body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

So if the user can scroll the gradient stops at the bottom of the original screen, and then repeats at intervals of the same height.

[image: sreen print of the problem]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background Gradient - Fill Page without scroll bars or repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470709/background-gradient-fill-page-without-scroll-bars-or-repeating)

Comment: body should not get the height:100%; rule, that is probably why bg is cut off. do you have different bg set on HTML and then BODY ? Your bits of code do not show your issue , nor why . Basicly the answer is yes.

Comment: Sorry, the last sentence confused me. What behavior are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, no only one of them has a background the other one i do nothing with, and no matter if i set the background on the html or the body tag the same happen where the gradient just stops and repeats at the bottom of the window screen. But if you need more code just ask.

Comment: Well G-Cyr you're king of right, short version: if i remove the height 100% on the body it keeps cutting of but if i remove it from both it works like i want it to, except if the content doesn't fill the screen then it cuts off at the bottom of the last element leaving some of the screen without a background.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or similar phrases to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing "solved" into the question is not.

Comment: Understood, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background: {your-gradient} no-repeat;
background-attachement: fixed;
min-height: 100%;
```

please test this

https://codepen.io/blue-haum/pen/JqobxJ

I hope it helpful for you

Comment: Well it works, except that the gradient follows the window instead of the page so it looks like the content moves on top of a static image, but thanks a lot this is good enough.